# Integrating Google Analytics with Smarty Template Engine

Tags: php, google-analytics, smarty

I'm having trouble with Google Analytics which refuses track my website that uses Smarty template engine. I have tried several ways, such as inserting the code before`</head>` and `</body>` tags, right after `<body>` tag, using `{literal}`, and PHP include. None of them seem to work, sadly. The last version of the code that I use at the moment is:

```
<script>
{literal}
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
{/literal}
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for your helps in advance, and sorry for being dumb.

Comment: I would recommend trying several locations for your <script> withint your html and checking for js error messages in your browser.

Comment: Magically the script above top was correct and it fixed the issue. Thanks for comment @sunny .